# Different thread share an object

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have this following code fragment which is accessed by different threads.

```
         try
         {            
            this.RefreshSettings();
            DateTime lastChecked = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(-1 * m_Settings.Interval);

            while (Run)
            {
                if ((DateTime.Now - lastChecked).TotalMilliseconds >= this.m_Settings.Interval)
                {
                    lastChecked = DateTime.Now;

                    if (this.ShouldNotify())
                    {
                        object LockObj = new object();

                        lock (LockObj)
                        {
                            this.Notify();
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Thread.Sleep(this.m_Settings.Interval);
            }
         }
```

As you can see, I only want ShouldNotify() method to be called after every given interval of time (m_settings.Interval). However, my problem is if two or more threads have called NotifyIfNecesarry function, they are sharing the lastChecked variable. So, if one thread resets its value to dateTime.Now, it gets reset for the others too.

How can I write that method so that each thread maintains its own lastChecked? Using Thread.Sleep is not an option because when the value of the bool Run is changed to false, I need the loop to exit instantaneously. If I have a thread.Sleep, and the thread is sleeping, the program won't exit until it checks the while condition, so there is a possible mak delay of m_settings.Interval.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the `lastChecked` variable is local, but you say it's being shared with other instances of this method.  Local variables are not shared between threads, so am I missing something or are you?

Comment: Where is this code? Is it in the thread's run or in another class?

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: lastChecked is local. I wasn't aware that local variables are not shared by threads. I guess something else must be causing the problem then.

Comment: The assumption @Coding Gorilla is making is that you have a separate object for each thread.  If you're sharing the object, then you still have a problem (possibly with your design).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should skip your loop and use for example [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx). And your lock is also out of place. It should created outside the loop and not per instance. When using a lock all threads must lock on the same object.

Comment: @Mickael I think you meant "skip your loop " not "skip your loo." Although the phrase may me smile because of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_to_My_Lou

Comment: I noticed it, and edited the answer :) Gave me a smile as well.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make any sense to `lock` on a locally created object. All the threads must `lock` on the same instance, otherwise there will be no synchronization.

The code below doesn't work as intended, as all the threads running this code will have their own local reference to a newly created instance of `object`.

```
object LockObj = new object();

lock (LockObj)
{
   this.Notify();
}
```

Also, since `lastChecked` is a local value type, each thread *will* have its own copy.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use a timer object?

Either: [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)
Or: [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I write that method so that
>   each thread maintains its own
>   lastChecked

You've already done  this.

Coding Gorilla had it right.

> The lastChecked variable is
>   local...Local variables are not shared
>   between threads